# MUI5 Stepper unexpected vertical line when calling from function

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, uistepper

Hi I am trying to develop MUI5 vertical stepper but got issue when rendering steps from function.
So, there is one extra connector line on top of first step.

https://codesandbox.io/s/customizedsteppers-material-demo-forked-vpgt8i?file=/demo.tsx

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the component as a function.

```
const steps = ["Step1", "Step2", "Step3"];

const RenderTree = ({ label }) => (
  <Step>
    <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
  </Step>
);

export default function CustomizedSteppers() {
  return (
    <Stepper orientation="vertical">
      {steps.map((label) => RenderTree({ label }))}
    </Stepper>
  );
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Sorry i fixed it